# Integer slicing in pandas different for rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Coming from R I try to get my head around integer slicing for pandas dataframes. 
What puzzles me is the different slicing behavior for rows and columns using the same integer/slice expression.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,6),
               'b': range(7,13),
               'c': range(14, 20)})
x.ix[0:2, 0:2]   # Why 3 x 2 and not 3 x 3 or 2 x 2?

    a   b
0   0   7
1   1   8
2   2   9
```

We get 3 rows but only 2 columns. In the docs I find that different from standard python, [label based slicing in pandas is inclusive](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#endpoints-are-inclusive). Does this apply here and is it inclusive for rows but not for columns then?

**Can someone explain the behavior and the rationale behind it?**

Comment: using `iloc` everything is fine 2x2 matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that there is a distinction between **label based indexing** and **position based indexing**. The first includes the end label, while typical python position based slicing does not include the last item.

In the example you give: `x.ix[0:2, 0:2]` the rows are being sliced based on the labels, so '2' is included (returning 3 rows), while the columns are sliced based on position, hence returning only 2 columns.

If you want guaranteed position based slicing (to return a 2x2 frame in this case), `iloc` is the indexer to use:

```
In [6]: x.iloc[0:2, 0:2]
Out[6]:
   a  b
0  0  7
1  1  8
```

For guaranteed position based slicing, you can use the `loc` indexer.
The `ix` indexer you are using, is more flexible (not strict in type of indexing). It is primarily label based, but will fall back to position based (when the labels are not found and you are using integers). This is the case in your example for the columns. For this reason, it is **recommended to always use `loc`/`iloc` instead of `ix`** (unless you need mixed label/position based indexing).

See the docs for a more detailed overview of the different types of indexers: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing

Answer (score 1):

,ix method is primarily label based with fallback to indexing...from docs online...

A primarily label-location based indexer, with integer position
fallback.

`.ix[]` supports mixed integer and label based access. It is
primarily label based, but will fall back to integer positional
access unless the corresponding axis is of integer type.

`.ix` is the most general indexer and will support any of the
inputs in `.loc` and `.iloc`. `.ix` also supports floating
point label schemes. `.ix` is exceptionally useful when dealing
with mixed positional and label based hierachical indexes.

However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access
and not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it's
usually better to be explicit and use `.iloc` or `.loc`.

So rationale is that it is trying to help you.   as with most things where software assume your intent it can have unexpected consequences.   where it does find the labels in the named range it does an inclusive selection at both ends as this is what you would normally want when you are analyzing data